# Django Pillow delete pip_build?

Tags: django

I'm unable to install Pillow due to a previous installation that failed.

This left some Pillow-files in a folder called "pip_build" in my temp. I need to delete it manually. But I cant delete it because it's files is open in some other program (?). I've tried closing my programs but I cant delete the folder.. Any ideas?

Comment: can you run `lsof | grep pip_build` and see what process the OS thinks is using that file. The you could try killing that process.

Comment: Thanks. Does that work for Windows command line?

Comment: I don't think windows has lsof but there are 2 options for a replacement http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx that should be able to let you know what process has a file open. I can't comment on which of them is best as I'm not on windows.